# Automate combination patterns for user input n

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, numbers

I have written program which gives all combinations till 'n', where the combination does not contain any repeating element.
Following is the code(for n=4):

```
    int[] arr = {0,1,2,3,4};
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+""+j);
            for (int k = j+1; k < arr.length; k++)
            {
                System.out.println(i+""+j+""+k);
                for (int l = k+1; l < arr.length; l++)
                {
                    System.out.println(i+""+j+""+k+""+l);
                    for (int m = l+1; m < arr.length; m++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(i+""+j+""+k+""+l+""+m);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output of which is:

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
0124
013
0134
014
02
023
0234
024
03
034
04
1
12
123
1234
124
13
134
14
2
23
234
24
3
34
4
```

I want to make it where user inputs any number(n) to perform similar functionality.

Comment: Good! What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: this is going to involve recursion

Comment: I am tinkering around (String... args), where I can pass any number of arguments, but still no progress.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am also sure it will involve recursion, still figuring out how :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have used recursion tag, I can't see recursion in your code. 
You can take user input through `BufferedReader`. You can solve the above problem using recursion. Give it a try first.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
int arr[] = new int[n];
String s[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: Actually I used recursion because I think solution to my problem lies in using recusion